# A step of gradient descent is upper bounded by a function of gradient norm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, gradient

In Appendix A.2 of paper "[Maximum a Posteriori Policy Optimisation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06920)"(Page 17), the authors say

[image]

$f$ in Equation $(23)$ is simply a gradient descent update w.r.t. $\theta$ from the original $f$. But I fail to see how the gradient norm is introduced in this upper bound. How can I derive that?